# Explain this Java for expression

Tags: java, for-loop

Can anyone explain this code to me?

```
class className {
    int[] coeffs;

    int count(int value) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int coeff: coeffs)
            if (coeff == value)
                count++;
        return count;
    }
}
```

What I really don't understand is this part:

```
for (int coeff: coeffs)
```

What is it mean? Thanks for help.

Comment: If you google "Java for loop," you can find the answer in literally the first response.

Comment: Read [Enhanced For-Loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Comment: It is a `foreach` loop in java.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work.

Comment: it as same as this 
`for(int x=0;x<coeffs.length;x++){
int coeff=coeffs[i];
//...
}`

Comment: @user2511414 Not quite. According to the Java Language Specification, it's equivalent to using an Iterator, not an indexed for loop. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Wow. I don't realize if it is just an another form of for-loop. Thanks all.

Comment: @Nick I see you buddy, I just want to same thing, we all know enough about Iterable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier versions of Java, there was only the C/Fortran style "for()" loop.

Java 5 (JDK 1.5, 2004) introduced a "foreach()" loop, with the syntax you've described:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop#Java

```
for (type item: iterableCollection) {
  // do something to item
}
```

It's worth noting that although the newer "foreach" syntax might be more "elegant", the "old" for loop index can actually be faster:

- https://www.java.net//node/662136

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4, you explained very complete, and it was very helpful.

Comment: The link on performance is antique. These things change on a minor-version basis and this is from two *major* versions ago.

Comment: There, I've just tested it with `jmh`. A loop summing 3200 `Integer`s achieves 1750 runs/second with indexed traversal vs. 1530 runs/second with enhanced for. That's just 14% difference, and if any real work was done in the iteration, it would evaporate completely.

Answer (score 1):

That is the enhanced for each loop to loop through the array `int[]` array.

Look at the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a foreach loop - it means that for every value in the array `coeffs` the code inside the for loop will be executed, with the variable `coeff` representing the value used during that particular iteration.

Comment: Thanks @robjohncox, your explanation is very simple and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's an enhanced for loop. It is structured as follows:

```
for(Object o: collection)
```

Basically, `objects` is an array of objects or primitive, or an Iterable of objects.

Java will iterate over the array or Iterable, set `o` to the object/value retrieved, and process the block. It allows for quick iteration without dealing with handling your own iterators/